# Check next loop iteration data unless at end of loop c#

Tags: c#, for-loop

I'm making a program which is creating an ASCII image. Based on the asterix input it produces different things. To start I'm making a basic outline however I have an issue where I cannot add something when checking last for loop iteration.

**Method code:**

```
        private List<string> DrawOutline(List<string> inputLines)
    {
        List<string> output = new List<string>();
        int door = r.Next(0, inputLines.Last().Length);
        for (int li = 0; li < inputLines.Count; li++)
        {
            char[] curLine = inputLines[li].ToCharArray();
            string outputLine1 = string.Empty;
            string outputLine2 = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < curLine.Length -1; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(curLine[i]);
                if (curLine[i] == '*')
                {
                    outputLine1 += "+---";
                    outputLine2 += "|   ";
                }
                else
                {
                    outputLine1 += "    ";
                    outputLine2 += "    ";
                }
                if(li < curLine.Length - 1)
                {
                    if (curLine[i] == '*' && curLine[i + 1] != '*')
                    {
                        outputLine1 += "+";
                        outputLine2 += "|";
                    }
                }
            }
            output.Add(outputLine1);
            output.Add(outputLine2); 
        }
        return output;
    }
```

When I run this, it works fine however will not add '+' and '|' to the last line of outputLines. This is because the line :

```
if(li < curLine.Length -1)
```

However without the -1 it will throw an exception because I am using [i+1] to decide something. Is there a way to check only if it won't throw an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check if the end of the array has been reached by using the OR ( || ) statement. If the first statement of the OR statement returns true, the second is not checked. This is called [short-circuiting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx).  No error should be thrown in this case.

```
private List<string> DrawOutline(List<string> inputLines)
{
    List<string> output = new List<string>();
    int door = r.Next(0, inputLines.Last().Length);
    for (int li = 0; li < inputLines.Count; li++)
    {
        char[] curLine = inputLines[li].ToCharArray();
        string outputLine1 = string.Empty;
        string outputLine2 = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < curLine.Length -1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(curLine[i]);
            if (curLine[i] == '*')
            {
                outputLine1 += "+---";
                outputLine2 += "|   ";
            }
            else
            {
                outputLine1 += "    ";
                outputLine2 += "    ";
            }

            if (curLine[i] == '*' && (curLine.Length == i+1 || curLine[i + 1] != '*'))
            {
                outputLine1 += "+";
                outputLine2 += "|";
            }

        }
        output.Add(outputLine1);
        output.Add(outputLine2); 
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `if (li < curLine.Length - 1)` to `if (i < curLine.Length - 1)`